# Symfony 3 login after registration with Advanced User Interface

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, symfony-security

I implemented Symfony security component. I have user entity that is stored in my database. It implements UserInterface and Serializable.

After registration I login user automatically with this part of code.

```
private function authenticateUser(EntityUser $user)
{
    $providerKey = 'secured_area';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
}
```

Now I removed UserInterface and implemented AdvancedUserInterface.

I addes is_active filed in my database.

I added:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="bool")
 */
private $isActive;
```

in my property list.

I added

```
public function isAccountNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isAccountNonLocked()
{
    return true;
}

public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}
```

and added in construct:

```
$this->isActive = 1;
```

When I register it saves my user in db like before and gives is_active column value of 1. But when I continue to execute authenticateUser method it make redirect loop and it just give me error page redirected too many times. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared out any session data since modifying the user object?

Comment: Yes I cleared all cookies and browsing data from chrome settings